# Android Studio Chipmunk - XML Layout Designer Split View Change Orientation

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I'm not sure what happened, but the Split XML design view is now showing horizontally instead of vertically. (Design View is on bottom and Code view is on top.) I can't find anywhere on the UI to change the orientation of the design and code panes.

[image: Split View]

Answer (score 35):

After playing around with the interface for longer than I'd like to admit...

**Clicking on the `Split` button again flips the UI between horizontal and vertical split screen.**

I'm not sure if this is a new feature in Android Chipmunk or if it's always been this way, but I could not find a duplicate question or answer on Stack Overflow or the web.

[image: Split Button]

Comment: this works, click again on "split icon" to toggle

Comment: Thanks! not intuitive at all I spent a fair amount of time trying to resolve this

Comment: Lol! Thank you so much I felt so dumb but satisfied at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar situation in version. `Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2`

I noticed that by pressing the `Split` button it became old value.

[image]